# Set UIImage as background of a UITableView from a UITableViewController programatically

Tags: ios, uiimage, uitableview

I have a MyTableViewController that is a subclass of `UITableViewController`. I have no `.xib` for it. And I'd like to set a `UIImage` I have as the background of the tableView from MyTableViewController. 
I tried to add on my `ViewDidLoad` : `self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background_img"]];`

But id didn't work. The img covered looked like this:

[image]

by doing:

```
UIImageView *bgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background_img"]];
bgImageView.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:bgImageView];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:bgImageView];
```

it looks like this:

[image]

How Could I get that working?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as follows:

Set the background image in the tableView in `viewDidLoad`:

```
UIImageView *bgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:<image>]];
bgImageView.frame = <tableView>.frame;
[<tableView> setBackgroundView:bgImageView];
```

Then set the colour of the cells to clear in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to make the table view background transparent:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tableView.opaque = NO;
```

Then set the background of the view:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background_img"]];
```

A better way to set the background image, though would be:

```
UIImageView *bgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background_img"]];
bgImageView.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:bgImageView];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:bgImageView];
```

Comment: @LucasPereira I added another method to the answer.